# Getting Error: Bad Request while retrieving the issues through vmware burp-rest-api

Tags: vmware, swagger-ui, burp

I am using vmware burp-rest-api . I have done the api testing and populated the sitemap.

Getting Error: Bad Request while retrieving the issues through swagger UI

Response body:

{
"timestamp": "2020-06-25T05:37:41.198+0000",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - Error at index 1 in: "1$"",
"path": "/burp/scanner/issues"
}